# VBA Type Mismatch on CustomOrder

Tags: vba

I have this code which works great:

```
Sub NewSortTest()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("A1:A20") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        "alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,golf,hotel,india,juliet", DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B20")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

I'm trying to modify the above code by using a variable called `keyRange` for `CustomOrder:=`:

```
Sub NewSortTest()
    Dim keyRange As String

    keyRange = "alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,golf,hotel,india,juliet"

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("A1:A20") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
        keyRange, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B20")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

However I get a Type Mismatch error.
I can see in MSDN that `CustomOrder:=` is of type `Variant`. I have tried `Variant` instead of `String`, but I get the same error.

**Edit:
CustomOrder is actually of type [SortField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb148007%28v=office.12%29.aspx).
How can I convert the String keyRange to a SortField object?**

Comment: You were right the first time. `CustomOrder` is a `Variant.` It's a property of a `SortField` object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glad you figured it out. The following also works (per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348579/excel-vba-custom-sorting)):

```
Sub NewSortTest()
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1:A20"), _
                                                        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                                        Order:=xlAscending, _
                                                        CustomOrder:=keyRange, _
                                                        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:B20")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub

Function keyRange() As String

keyRange = "alpha,bravo,charlie,delta,echo,foxtrot,golf,hotel,india,juliet"

End Function
```

**Edit: Even easier**

```
CustomOrder:=CVar(keyRange)
```

**Edit: Why Does This Work?**

I've been trying to figure that out myself. The help documentation on the `CustomOrder` property lacks any meat, as you found out in your search. I've been experimenting with different things to see if I could get at an answer, and I haven't had much luck. I think `CustomOrder` is doing some magic in the background. It does just fine with a `String` literal or a `Long`, as you found out. And it has no poblem with a `String` properly cast as `Variant`. But it doesn't like `String` variables. It must have something to do with `String` variables being reference types. I have no idea why it wouldn't be able to handle that, but I also don't know how it creates a custom list on the fly from a `String` literal. If you find anything that explains it, I'd love to know.

Comment: Thankyou. Yours was much simpler.

Comment: Can you explain why your version works but mine doesn't?

Why does getting keyRange from a function work, but just declaring it with Dim keyRange As String doesn't?

Answer (score 3):

I worked it out.
You need to use a ListArray:

```
Sub NewSortTest()
    Dim keyRange As Variant
    Dim sortNum As Long

    keyRange = Array("alpha", "bravo", "charlie", "delta", "echo", "foxtrot", "golf", "hotel", "india", "juliet")

    Application.AddCustomList ListArray:=keyRange
    sortNum = Application.CustomListCount

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add key:=Range("A1:A20"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:=sortNum, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:B20")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but figured my approach seems worth sharing.

I stored the SortField as a variable then set the CustomOrder property as per below, it seems the complier will take the delimited string and convert it to whatever it requires. FYI loNewReport is a ListObject

```
Dim sField As SortField
Set sField = loNewReport.Sort.SortFields.Add(loNewReport.ListColumns("Branch").DataBodyRange, xlSortOnValues, xlAscending)
sField.CustomOrder = "QLD, NSW, VIC"
loNewReport.Sort.Apply
Set sField = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked carefully at using a function to populate the custom order string as shown in a previous answer.

I ignored it at first before realising that this probably works because it is returning a literal string not an ordinary string.

Anyway it works so thanks to previous responders. THis is what I came up with to solve my problem. `keyRange` fits into the `.SortFields.Add` string as demonstrated by the previous replies.

```
Function keyRange() As String
    'Create a string used to sort data on another sheet.
    'Becomes part of the .SortFields.Add statement as CustomOrder:=keyfield
    'CustomOrder items are in Col "A" of a sheet. The list can change over time
    'and is refreshed from an import from a database.
    With Sheets("Home Groups")
        lic = lastInCol(.Range("A1"))       'Gets the last used cell in column A
                                            'lastInCol is one of John Walkenbach's routines
                                            'From his book Excel 2010 Power Programming with VBA
       'Create a string from those items from row 2 to the last used row
        For rw = 2 To lic
            If rw = 2 Then
                keyRange = .Cells(rw, 1)        'This is the first item
            Else
                keyRange = keyRange & "," & .Cells(rw, 1)   'The remaining items - comma separated
            End If
        Next rw
    End With
End Function
```