# Sorting using a custom order in excel gives error 1004

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I'm trying to sort data in a sheet with several columns by two of the columns -- first by column B (alphabetically), then by column C (using the custom order "G, D, M, F" -- these are the only values that occur in the column). However, when I try to run the code, I get the error

```
1004 - Unable to get the Sort property of the Range class
```

So here's what I'm working with. Earlier in the code I have

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
```

Then here's the part where I get the error:

```
Range("A2:Y" & lastrow).Sort.SortFields. _
Add Key:=Range("C2:C" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
DataOption:=xlSortNormal
Range("A2:Y" & lastrow).Sort.SortFields. _
Add Key:=Range("B2:B" & lastrow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
CustomOrder:="G,D,M,F", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? Also possible related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366188/vba-type-mismatch-on-customorder

Comment: `CustomOrder:="G,D,M,F", DataOption:=xlSortNormal` also for this part is each of the G D M F ment to be seperate or as one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to add the custom sort order into the custom lists as an array first. When sorting, you will have to sort twice. Once on the secondary custom sort order and then on the primary non-custom key.

```
Dim vCOLs As Variant

vCOLs = Array("G", "D", "M", "F")

With Application
    '.ScreenUpdating = False
    '.EnableEvents = False
    .AddCustomList ListArray:=vCOLs
End With

With Worksheets("sheet2")
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        'first sort on the secondary custom sort on column B
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes, _
                    OrderCustom:=Application.CustomListCount + 1
        'next sort on the primary key; column C
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes

    End With
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
End With
```

I'm not entirely sure what is going on with your row 1. Your original code starts the sort in row 2 but gives no indication whether you have a header row or not.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks so much. Row 1 is indeed a header row, I probably should have mentioned that.