# Sorting by Text Value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

After running a VBA function on my spreadsheet, I would like to re-sort the data automatically, so the user doesn't have to. The sort options I'm trying to complete are as follows:

[image]

And my vba code is currently:

```
Columns("A:AA").Sort key1:=Range("C1:C1"), order1:=xlAscending, key2:=Range("G1:G1"), order2:=xlAscending, key3:=Range("A1:A1"), order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

As you can see, column A will sort properly, although the other 2 will not sort based on the `Fail, Dismissed, Passed` criteria and the `Critical, High, Medium, Low`

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Does anyone know a way to specify these Sort Orders?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576540/sorting-using-a-custom-order-in-excel-gives-error-1004

Comment: Have you used the Macro Recorder to see what code is generated if you do that sort manually?

Comment: Yea Scott, the question you linked to answers my question within his question :P (although I don't think it's a duplicate)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the macro recorder led me to the following code:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("C:C"), _
                         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, _
                         CustomOrder:="Fail,Dismissed,Passed", _
                         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("G:G"), _
                         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, _
                         CustomOrder:="Critical,High,Medium,Low", _
                         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=.Range("A:A"), _
                         SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                         Order:=xlAscending, _
                         DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Sort.SetRange .Range("A:AA")
    .Sort.Header = xlYes
    .Sort.MatchCase = False
    .Sort.Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .Sort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Sort.Apply
End With
```

Hopefully that should do what you want.