# Define custom sort order

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have data being sorted across multiple fields, including a couple that are custom sort orders.  One of the custom sorts is by sizes, which includes 57 categories.  If I declare the sort variable as

```
Const SizeSort As String = "XXS,2XS,XS,S,M,L,XL,1X,2XL,2X,XXL,2X/3X,... (out to 57 items)
```

And use:

```
.SortFields.Add Key:=Columns("H"), CustomOrder:=SizeSort
```

everything works fine.  However, I would like the ability for someone to change the sort order without having to get inside the code itself.  I was playing with the idea of saving a workbook that contained the current sort order in a column, then using:

```
unicorns = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To unicorns
    SizeSort = SizeSort & "," & Range("A" & i)
Next i
SizeSort = Right(SizeSort, Len(SizeSort) - 1)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work - I get Run-Time error 13-Type Mismatch.  I imagine it has something to do with the Const declaration, but I can't for the life of me figure out why - both strings *look* identical when viewed in the Immediate window.

Comment: This thread might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366188/vba-type-mismatch-on-customorder

Comment: @SJR Digging through that thread, the answer is to use a separate Function to build your sort string, and then call it directly from the .Sort, CustomOrder:= statement.  Weird, but it works!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, here is the method that works, (adapting from [VBA Type Mismatch on CustomOrder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22366188/vba-type-mismatch-on-customorder), link provided by SJR):

Define a Function that builds your sort list:

```
Function Sortlist(TmpName) As String
    '(TmpName =  name of file with your sort values)

    Dim unicorns, i As Long
    Dim TmpBook as Workbook
    Set TmpBook = Workbooks.Open(TmpName)
    unicorns = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To unicorns
        Sortlist = Sortlist & "," & Range("A" & i)
    Next i
    Sortlist = Right(Sortlist, Len(Sortlist) - 1)  'trim the leading ","
    TmpBook.Close

End Function
```

Then call that function directly from your Sort procedure:

```
 With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SetRange Range("A1:M" & LR)
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns("A")
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns("B")
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns("L"), CustomOrder:=YNSort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Columns("H"), CustomOrder:=Sortlist(filename)
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With
```

I would only recommend this for extremely long custom sort lists, or for lists that need to be changed frequently without editing the program itself.  But I can confirm for sure that it works this way... I would appreciate if someone could tell me WHY, though!