# Unexpected results from custom sort using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am trying to sort a table in my spreadsheet, using a custom sort. After a bit back and forth, I came up with this macro:

```
Sub sort_SI()
    With Resultat_SI.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SetRange Resultat_SI.Range(Resultat_SI.Range("A1"), Resultat_SI.Range("J" & Resultat_SI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Resultat_SI.Columns("J"), CustomOrder:=Join(Application.Transpose(Fargar.ListObjects("Fargekoder").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange), ",")
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

It runs just fine, and the order of my entries does change, after the sub is finished, but there seems no sense to the ordering. At the very least I would expect the lines with the same values in column J to be grouped together, but this does not seem to be the case.

Printing `Sort.SetRange`to the immediate window shows that it is

- `$A$1:$J$20`

as expected, while `Join(Application.Transpose(Fargar.ListObjects("Fargekoder").ListColumns(3).DataBodyRange), ",")` gives

- `Green,Brown,Black,Black (600/610),Unmarked,Pink,Blue,White,White (378/428),Yellow,Ukjent,Red`

also as expected.

The two sheets I am referencing in the sub looks like this:

**Resultat_SI**

[image]

**Fargekoder**

[image]

Basically I want my table in Resultat_SI to be sorted in the same order as the colors appear in the table in Fargekoder, with blank results appearing at the bottom, but I am failing miserably at achieving this result. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Ugh, nevermind, I shouldn't have locked the cell references in my formulas - once I removed that it works as expected :-p

Comment: Might be worth adding that as an answer (possibly with bit more details of your findings) and accepting it? It will not only close the query but also help anyone in the future if the come across this post

Comment: @zac Yeah, I was trying to decide between that or just deleting the question. Not sure how applicable it will be for other people....

Comment: Your code seems a good way to setup a custom sort. I would use it.. so I would say, definitely worth an answer and not deletion

Comment: @zac I got the format of the sort from this Q/A, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838064/define-custom-sort-order, so it already exists on SO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define custom sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46838064/define-custom-sort-order)

Comment: Fare shout. In which case, delete away :)

Comment: @Chrismas007 While the format of the sort is similar to the Q/A i linked earlier, I fail to see how the problem here is at all similar to what is presented in the other question. Could you please expand on why you think it is a duplicate?

Comment: @eirikdaude you literally said "it already exists on SO" so I voted to close as duplicate because of your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with sorting my table was not with the sorting code itself, but rather with the formulas used to populate the table. I had locked the cell references in the formulas, meaning that once a line had been sorted to a different location in the table, the formulas on that line *still referenced whatever was now shown to its previous location*.

In other words, all it took to fix the problem was removing one `$` from each cell reference, in order to have them change to the appropriate cells after having been sorted.

I.e. changing

- `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H$2;Fargekoder;3;FALSE);"")`

to

- `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($H2;Fargekoder;3;FALSE);"")`

was all it took.